# Django,if using raw SQL, what steps should I take to avoid SQL injection attacks?

Tags: sql, django, sql-injection

I have read that ORM's should minimise the possibilities of SQL injection attacks. However in Django, sometimes the ORM is somewhat limited, and I need to use raw SQL. What steps should I take to avoid SQL injection attacks?

Currently I would know to check for semicolons in the query string, but not much else. If I use parametrised queries, will this solve the problem? Are there any libraries to pass the string to, that will check it for me?

Comment: I am curious to know what have you tried that reached the limits of the ORM?

Comment: Conditional aggregates for starters. Complex joins become difficult to express.

Comment: You can get [conditional aggregates](https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-aggregate-if); and I don't know about complex joins (care to provide an example?). All the joins I needed I was able to finagle with the ORM.

Comment: Ahhh, that wasn't available when I was looking for it a couple of years back.

Comment: I wasn't able to express joins on more than one field: SELECT fields FROM table_A a JOIN table_B b ON (b.first_fk = a.id AND b.second_fk = a.second_field)

Comment: This is also available in the ORM, have a look at the [`F` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.F) and [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) in the manual.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get some queries to work. Expressing sub queries in the select did not work either. After a certain amount of wrestling, I don't see the advantage of shoehorning queries into the ORM, when it is significantly easier to do it in SQL.

Comment: I think you gave up on the ORM too easily. `raw` is only rarely used in practice.

Comment: If it doesn't work, it doesn't work. There was no conditional aggregates module available when I needed it. It was not a case of giving up too easily. I have coaxed it into doing fairly complex queries. The ORM is there to save time and effort, not make it more difficult. Why else would they have included the option for raw SQL if it wasn't a problem?

Comment: I don't understand why people are so glued to the ORM.  If you can easily do what you need to do in SQL, and the ORM method is highly complex and hard to read and troubleshoot, just use SQL, for pete's sake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) the following:

> If you need to perform parameterized queries, you can use the params
>   argument to `raw()`:

```
>>> lname = 'Doe'
>>> Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE last_name = %s', [lname])
```

> `params` is a list or dictionary of parameters. You’ll use `%s`
>   placeholders in the query string for a list, or `%(key)s` placeholders
>   for a dictionary (where key is replaced by a dictionary key, of
>   course), regardless of your database engine. Such placeholders will be
>   replaced with parameters from the params argument.

This is also the standard way to pass parameters using Python's DB-API, which will sanitize your queries correctly.

Whatever you do, don't do string interpolation.

Comment: OK, is that the ONLY things I need to do?