# Django sql injection protection

Tags: django, security, sql-injection

Is it necessary to do custom cleaning of form data received from fields where the user is limited to selecting from pre-defined valid choices? For example radio buttons, choicefields, etc.

I have a situation where a database select is performed but the columns used in that select are defined by the user. The user is presented with pre-defined valid choices (radio buttons, choicefields) which represent table columns.

When that form is received do I need to do custom cleaning of that data to once again check that the data is valid? In other words, would it somehow be possible for the user to have POSTed invalid data even though I limited their choices to valid data?

Comment: sql injection protection is built into django ORM queries. If you are not using them provide a specific example

Comment: You'll have to check that the value is one of the allowed columns, the user can send anything, but as long as you're using Django forms, that'll be done for you. However, that's not sql injection, that's simple data validation.

Comment: In this specific case the select query is very complex involving several tables, joins, etc with the result needing to be in a pandas dataframe to be manipulated further. I am therefore using pandas read_sql_query using django.db.connection

Comment: Thanks @knbk, that is what I was trying to ask. Yes I am using django forms. I was just asking is it possible for the user to submit data that wasn't present in predefined valid radio boxes, choicefields. I have no idea how that would be possiblie? But if it is, I would need to check for that).

Comment: Any modern browser allows you to directly edit the HTML of a page and change the options. Or you can just use any command-line tool to send a HTTP request with arbitrary data. However, Django forms validate the data, so neither of these will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django,if using raw SQL, what steps should I take to avoid SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753605/django-if-using-raw-sql-what-steps-should-i-take-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks)